# Unresolved reference kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, build-error

Для начала - я гуглил много по по ошибкам, которые получаю и использовал и испробовал всё то, что нашёл. Однако продолжаю их получать.

Мой build.gradle файл проекта выглядит так

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.2.31"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        .....
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        .....
    }
}
```

build.gradle уровня модуля выглядит так

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    .........
    androidExtensions {
        experimental = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    ..........
    // kotlin
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    .........
}
```

Но я продолжаю получать следующие ошибки

```
e: \pages\BaseActivity.kt: (16, 9): Unresolved reference: window
e: \pages\GameActivity.kt: (37, 21): Unresolved reference: startActivity
e: \pages\MenuActivity.kt: (30, 21): Unresolved reference: startActivity
e: \util\FileUtil.kt: (19, 31): Unresolved reference: assets
e: \util\FileUtil.kt: (21, 51): Unresolved reference: it
e: \viewmodel\MenuViewModel.kt: (42, 70): Unresolved reference: finish
```

Как вы можете заметить - не распознаются ссылки на стандартные методы, такие как 'startActivity' или 'finish'. Почему же тогда котлин не может их распознать?

Я начал получать эти ошибки после того как проапдейтил проект - версии гредла и гредл плагина, версию плагина котлин и версии многих библиотек, но после того, как я попробовал все это продаундгрейдить - ошибки не ушли.

Никто не сталквался с такой проблемой?

Answer (score 2):

Я нашел решение. Это была зависимость, которая ломала сборку.

```
implementation group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version: '1.3.148'
```

Я добавлял её для того, чтобы потестировать Exposed в одно время с обновлением всех версий в build.gradle, поэтому не обратил на неё внимания сразу, решил, что это был апдейт какого то плагина или билд вёршна.

Так что если Вы получаете скоуп подобных ошибок - проблема может быть в зависимости, которая ломает сборку, попробуйте закомментить последние добавленные и посмотреть, не поможет ли это

Answer (score 0):

В `build.gradle` уровня проекта добавьте такую зависимость:

```
buildscript {
   .....
   dependencies {
      .....
      classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"
      .....
   }
}
```

И после пересоберите проект

Comment: Я пробовал это решение, но оно не сработало + с версии плагина 1.3, кажется, эту зависимость добавлять не обязательно. Я нашел решение, сейчас напишу ответ